# Delegate method not invoked in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, delegates, xceed

I am trying to call a delegate to validate the incoming SSL Certificates from FTP Server.

**When I put a debug point in OnCertificateReceived function, the execution never stops**, and the SSL Certificate is never validated.

**Can someone please point out if I am doing anything wrong here.**

```
class Program
{

var hostname = '';
var username = '';
var password = '';

public static void main()
{
  new Program().XceedFtpWithSSL();
}

void XceedFtpWithSSL()
{
connection = new FtpConnection(hostname,21,username,password,AuthenticationMethod.TlsAuto,VerificationFlags.None,null,DataChannelProtection.Private,false);

connection.CertificateReceived += new CertificateReceivedEventHandler( this.OnCertificateReceived );
}

// When I put debug point in this method, execution never stops

private void OnCertificateReceived(object sender, CertificateReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // The Status argument property tells you if the server certificate was accepted
            // based on the VerificationFlags you provided.
            if (e.Status != VerificationStatus.ValidCertificate)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to accept this certificate anyway? [Y/N]");
                int answer = Console.Read();

                if ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'))
                {
                    e.Action = VerificationAction.Accept;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid certificate received from server.");
                // e.Action's default value is VerificationAction.Accept
            }
        } // End of Delegate

}//End of class
```

Comment: I am going to guess you need to actually do something to have the class open a connection. Have you tried calling the `TestConnection()` method to verify that connections are possible?

Comment: @Prasoon: Are you saying `OnCertificateReceived` never executes? Or does it execute then hang?

Comment: yes, it never executes and I am referring to Xceed's documentation where they are first initializing the connection and then calling the delegate to validate the Certificate.

Comment: The documentation states it **initializes a new instance**, not a connection. I think the connection attempt may occur when you actually try to do something with `FtpFile` or `FtpFolder`. Like I said before, call the `TestConnection()` method, see if it causes `OnCertificateReceived` to execute.

Comment: It is probably already received before the event is registered?

Comment: @JuanR I called the TestConnection() method after initializing the connection and still oncertificateReceived won't execute.

Comment: The certificate validation example in the Xceed documentation uses the `FtpClient` interface. You're using the "file system" interface. The documentation does not say if `FtpConnection::TestConnection` negotiates TLS when you use "explicit TLS", it says that it "checks if a connection is possible". That might just mean opening a socket, and not even sending/receiving the welcom message.

Try to actually do an operation, for example listing all files in the folder (https://s12316.pcdn.co/wp-content/documentation/xceed-filesystem-for-net/webframe.html#topic305.html). See what happens then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you are applying an event to the delegate, for him to execute defato must have some function in FtpConnection that executes this delegate event: Ex

```
public delegate void ExDelegate(string value);

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        connection.ExDelegate += OnConnection_ExDelegate;
        connection.Init();
    }

    public static void OnConnection_ExDelegate(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Connection
{
    public event ExDelegate ExDelegate;

    public void Init()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        ExDelegate?.Invoke(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```